# How to simplify my JS functions in a nutrition calculator?

Tags: javascript, calc

https://codepen.io/TBD007/pen/zYxgWbv

Trying to avoid having to write a function for each button's onclick event. Currently i am using a separate function for each onclick. I am pretty sure there is a way to put all that into one single function but i just can't figure it out on my own.. Any idea to simplify the js code in order to calculate the values? Help is very much appreciated!

```js
function test() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test2() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test2").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test3() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test3").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Here's a the full snippet:

```js
var result = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;

function test() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test2() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test2").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test3() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test3").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test4() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test4").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test5() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test5").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test6() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test6").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test7() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test7").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test8() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test8").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test9() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test9").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test10() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test10").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test11() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test11").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test12() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test12").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test13() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test13").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function test14() {
  var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  var x = document.getElementById("test14").getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}

function add() {
  var y = document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML;
  var z = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML = Number(y) + Number(z);
}

function sub() {
  var y = document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML;
  var z = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML = Number(z) - Number(y);
}

function clearentry() {
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = 0;
  document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML = 0;
}
```

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(26, 26, 43, 0.496), rgba(26, 26, 43, 0.86)), url("https://www.miss.at/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Technik-Panne-McDonalds-muss-400.000-Euro-an-Gewinner-zahlen-1024x683.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
  position: relative;
}

#txtResult {
  width: 257px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  background: rgba(40, 40, 53, 0.69);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 1px gray;
}

#txtResultItem {
  width: 257px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  background: rgba(40, 40, 53, 0.69);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 1px gray;
}

button {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-size: contain;
}

#btnClearEntry {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  max-height: 60px;
  max-width: 60px;
}

#btn1 {
  background-image: url("https://img.scoop.it/aImnklIQUA5uWH212vRoWjl72eJkfbmt4t8yenImKBVvK0kTmF0xjctABnaLJIm9");
}

#btn2 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-big-mac.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn3 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-hamburger.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn4 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-6-chicken-mcnuggets.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn5 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-crispy-caesar-chicken-mcwrap.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn6 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-fries-medium.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn7 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-blueberry-muffin-hero.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn8 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-coca-cola.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn9 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-side-caesar-salad.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn10 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-egg-mcmuffin.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn11 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-filet-o-fish.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn12 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-quarter-pounder-cheese.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn13 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-baked-apple-pie.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn14 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-hot-fudge-sundae.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$")
}

#logo {
  background-image: url("http://www.mcdonalds.at/sites/default/files/cms/social_media/sharelogo.png");
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 0px solid rgba(40, 40, 53, 0.89);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px black;
}

#btnClearEntry {
  background: rgba(40, 40, 53, 0.79);
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px black;
}

#btnplus {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px black;
}

#btnminus {
  color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 223, 15, 1);
  border: 1px solid silver;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px black;
}

#logo {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.calculator {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.648);
  padding: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  position: relative;
}

button[aria-label]:hover:after {
  content: attr(aria-label);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20;
  background: red;
  color: yellow;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>

    <div class="main">

      <div class="calculator">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
              <div style="color:white; font-family:sans-serif;font-size:20px;" id="txtResult" readonly="readonly"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
              <div style="color:white; font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;" id="txtResultItem"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="test" value="475"><button onclick="test()" id="btn1" aria-label="Happy Meal"></button></td>
            <td id="test2" value="540">
              <button onclick="test2()" id="btn2" aria-label="Big Mac"></button>
            </td>
            <td><a href="https://www.mcdonalds.at/kalorienrechner" target="_blank"><button aria-label="All Products" id="logo" ></button></a></td>
            <td><button id="btnClearEntry" onclick="clearentry()">CE</button></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="test3" value="200"><button onclick="test3()" id="btn3" aria-label="Hamburger"></button></td>
            <td id="test4" value="250"><button onclick="test4()" id="btn4" aria-label="6 Chicken Nuggets"></button></td>
            <td id="test5" value="570"><button onclick="test5()" id="btn5" aria-label="Crispy Chicken Wrap"></button></td>
            <td><button id="btnplus" onclick="add()"><b>+</b></button></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="test6" value="350"><button onclick="test6()" id="btn6" aria-label="Big Fries"></button></td>
            <td id="test7" value="430"><button onclick="test7()" id="btn7" aria-label="Blueberry Muffin"></button></td>
            <td id="test8" value="190"><button onclick="test8()" id="btn8" aria-label="Coke"></button></td>
            <td><button id="btnminus" onclick="sub()"><b>-</b></button></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="test9" value="360"><button onclick="test9()" id="btn9" aria-label="Cesars salad"></button></td>
            <td id="test10" value="290"><button onclick="test10()" id="btn10" aria-label="Egg McMuffin"></button></td>
            <td id="test11" value="360"><button onclick="test11()" id="btn11" aria-label="Fish Mac"></button></td>
            <td id="test12" value="490"><button onclick="test12()" id="btn12" aria-label="Royal with Cheese"></button></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="test13" value="270"><button onclick="test13()" id="btn13" aria-label="Baked Apple Pie"></button></td>
            <td id="test14" value="340"><button onclick="test14()" id="btn14" aria-label="Mc Sundae"></button></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>

        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: `function test3(id){
    var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML ;
    var x=document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML=x;
}`
 you can try by  this way. pass the id's to the functions.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shorter version

I use the following techniques

- unobtrusive event handler
- object to hold the names and values
- DOM manipulation (sorry I got lazy on the operators)
- removed the button from the link and used an image instead for the logo

```js
const buttons = {
  "Happy Meal": 475,
  "Big Mac": 540,
  "Hamburger": 200,
  "6 Chicken Nuggets": 250,
  "Crispy Chicken Wrap": 570,
  "Big Fries": 350,
  "Blueberry Muffin": 430,
  "Coke": 190,
  "Cesars salad": 360,
  "Egg McMuffin": 290,
  "Fish Mac": 360,
  "Royal with Cheese": 490,
  "Baked Apple Pie": 270,
  "Mc Sundae": 340
}
const operators = [
  '<a href="https://www.mcdonalds.at/kalorienrechner" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.mcdonalds.at/sites/default/files/cms/social_media/sharelogo.png" aria-label="All Products" id="logo" ></img></a>',
  '<button id="btnClearEntry" onclick="clearentry()">CE</button>',
  '<button id="btnplus" onclick="add()"><b>+</b></button>',
  '<button id="btnminus" onclick="sub()"><b>-</b></button>'
]
const tb = document.querySelector(".calculator table tbody");
let cnt = 0;
let tr = document.createElement("tr");
for (let but in buttons) {
  cnt++;
  td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="btn' + cnt + '" aria-label="' + but + '" value="' + buttons[but] + '"></button>';
  tr.appendChild(td)

  if (cnt % 3 === 0) {
    if (operators.length > 0) {
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = operators.shift()
    }
    tr.appendChild(td);
    tb.appendChild(tr);
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
  }
}
tb.appendChild(tr);

tb.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type && tgt.type === "button") {
    document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = tgt.value;
  }
});

function add() {
  var y = document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML;
  var z = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML = Number(y) + Number(z);
}

function sub() {
  var y = document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML;
  var z = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML = Number(z) - Number(y);
}

function clearentry() {
  document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = 0;
  document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML = 0;
}
```

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(26, 26, 43, 0.496), rgba(26, 26, 43, 0.86)), url("https://www.miss.at/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Technik-Panne-McDonalds-muss-400.000-Euro-an-Gewinner-zahlen-1024x683.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
  position: relative;
}

#txtResult {
  width: 257px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  background: rgba(40, 40, 53, 0.69);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 1px gray;
}

#txtResultItem {
  width: 257px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  background: rgba(40, 40, 53, 0.69);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 1px gray;
}

button {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-size: contain;
}

#btnClearEntry {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  max-height: 60px;
  max-width: 60px;
}

#btn1 {
  background-image: url("https://img.scoop.it/aImnklIQUA5uWH212vRoWjl72eJkfbmt4t8yenImKBVvK0kTmF0xjctABnaLJIm9");
}

#btn2 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-big-mac.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn3 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-hamburger.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn4 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-6-chicken-mcnuggets.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn5 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-crispy-caesar-chicken-mcwrap.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn6 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-fries-medium.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn7 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-blueberry-muffin-hero.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn8 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-coca-cola.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn9 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-side-caesar-salad.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn10 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-egg-mcmuffin.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn11 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-filet-o-fish.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn12 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-quarter-pounder-cheese.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn13 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-baked-apple-pie.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$");
}

#btn14 {
  background-image: url("https://www.mcdonalds.com/is/image/content/dam/ca/nfl/web/nutrition/products/nutrition/en/mcdonalds-hot-fudge-sundae.png?$Nutritional_Desktop$")
}

#logo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 0px solid rgba(40, 40, 53, 0.89);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px black;
}

#btnClearEntry {
  background: rgba(40, 40, 53, 0.79);
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px black;
}

#btnplus {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px black;
}

#btnminus {
  color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 223, 15, 1);
  border: 1px solid silver;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px black;
}

#logo {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.calculator {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.648);
  padding: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  position: relative;
}

button[aria-label]:hover:after {
  content: attr(aria-label);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20;
  background: red;
  color: yellow;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="calc.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">

    <div class="calculator">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <div style="color:white; font-family:sans-serif;font-size:20px;" id="txtResult" readonly="readonly"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <div style="color:white; font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;" id="txtResultItem"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all of these functions with this;

```js
function test(elementId){
    var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML ;
    var x = document.getElementById(elementId).getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}
```

and then in your onClick handlers do something like

- test('test')
- test('test2')
- test('test3')

and just pass in the id of the element as a string value to the function.

Answer (score 0):

So, only variable among your functions is the id of the element from which you are getting `x`, you can write a function that accepts this variable as parameter and pass it to the function when calling it

```
function test(id){
    var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML ;
    var x = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```
<button onclick="test('test')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , add an argument for a function with numerics as 1,2,3..etc and pass that value and append the same in the document.getElementById("test"+itemValue).getAttribute("value") value. 
Dynamically pass the inputs from the click event.

```
function test(itemValue){
    var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML ;
    var x=document.getElementById("test"+itemValue).getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML=x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below snipet

```js
function test(){
    thisObj=event.target;
    var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML ;
    var x=thisObj.getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML=x;


}
```

```html
<div id="txtResult"></div>
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="test()" />
<input type="button" value="2" onclick="test()" />
<input type="button" value="3" onclick="test()" />
<div id="txtResultItem"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` reference at `onclick` event handler (without passing extra arguments like `test3` etc)

```js
function test(item){
    console.log(item.value)
}
```

```html
<div><button value="1" onclick="test(this)">1</button></div>
<div><button value="2" onclick="test(this)">2</button></div>
<div><button value="3" onclick="test(this)">3</button></div>
```

Or you can use `event.target`:

```js
function test(){
    var item  = event.target;
    console.log(item.value)
}
```

```html
<div><button value="1" onclick="test()">1</button></div>
<div><button value="2" onclick="test()">2</button></div>
<div><button value="3" onclick="test()">3</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single function that passes in the id of the element you want to use as `var x`.

**Javascript**

```
function test_reuse(elid){
var summe = document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML ;
var x=document.getElementById(elid).getAttribute("value");
document.getElementById("txtResultItem").innerHTML=x;
```

}

**Sample HTML element**

```
<td id="test3" value="200"><button onclick="test_reuse('test3')" id="btn3" aria-label="Hamburger"></button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have your buttons fire an event upon click, and given the event you can get the ID of the corresponding button and update the UI accordingly.

```js
<td id="test3" value="200"><button onclick="test_general(event)" id="btn3" aria-label="Hamburger"></button></td>


....

//JS

function test_general(event){
  var button_id = event.target.id
  // DO SOMETHING NOW THAT YOU HAVE THE ID OF BUTTON
  console.log(button_id)    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers:

- Having `id` on element can help you uniquely identify but the it becomes huge to keep track of. Use classes or composite selectors to achieve this.
- Adding `onClick` on markup will pose a security threat as anyone can inspect your element and see whats going on. Using `.addEventListener` will encapsulate the code and keeps markup clean.
- Having 1-1 mapping of button/ handler is an overkill. You can add any meta information as a part of `data-` tag and can be retrieved to process.

Following is the updated code: https://codepen.io/TBD007/pen/zYxgWbv which addresses above pointers.

Please note, I added `data-number` attribute in HTML